# Make shapes with inequality

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry, inequality, euclidean-geometry

> The following set : 
>   $$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x+y \leq 1, x\geq 0, y \geq 0 \}$$
>   is a triangle. One way to see it is simply that we draw all points under the line of equation $y = 1-x$ with positive coordinates.

My question is :

- Is it possible with inequalities (just as the one that describe a triangle) to draw some other nice shapes like parallelogram or more generally regular polygons ?
- Moreover I suspect that there is some linear algebra behind these inequalities. So maybe for example linear algebra can help proving that the above inequality makes a triangle.

Thank you !

Comment: This is possible. Take for example the rectangle $\{|x|=|y|=1, -1\leq x\leq 1, -1\leq y\leq 1\}$. Look up "parametrisation of curves" for a general treatment.

Comment: you can write any polygons as a union of triangles by the way.

Comment: @James Thank you for the reference !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In fact, *every* convex polygon can be described as

$$\{(x,y)| a_1x + b_1 y\leq c_1, a_2x+b_2x\leq c_2,\dots, a_nx + b_nx \leq c_n\}$$

or, in linear algebra terms:

> For every convex polygon $P$, there exists some matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times 2}$ and a vector $c\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $$P=\left\{(x,y)| A\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\leq c\right\}$$

Comment: That's great thank you ! Is there a way to describe the matrix ? For example if I want to draw a convex polygone with vertex : $(x_1,y_1), ..., (x_n, y_n)$ ?

Comment: @dghkgfzyukz Each line in the polygon has an implicit equation, i.e., for every line of the polygon, there exist $a,b,c$ such that the line is described by the equation $ax+by=c$. Then the inequality $ax+by\leq c$ describes one side of that line. If the polygon is on that side of the line, then $[a,b]$ is one row of the matrix $A$, and $c$ is one component of the vector c.

Comment: Ok I understand, thank you for the explanation.